# Select People and Groups dialog is having wrong format on IE 10

Tags: sharepoint-designer, development, css, people-picker

I have created a site column of type “People or Group”. Which will automatically be associated with the following user selection dialog:-

[image]

But as shown in the above picture the dialog will not be showing the users as the box is very small !! can anyone advice how to fix this problem. I am using IE 10 64x , while if I used Firefox it will show the dialog correctly.

now using IE developer tool I changed the height for the resultcontent from 45px to be 350px and it expand the username area well, but when I write the following inside my custom css file , it did not have any effect:-

```
#resultcontent

{

height:350px;

}
```

Can anyone advice on this ?

Comment: Try `height:350px !important;`

Comment: i define the following inside my custom css "#resultcontent    
{
    height:350px !important;    
}
.ms-pickerresultdiv
{
    height:350px !important;    
}" but did not solve the problem

Comment: Also try defining min-height:350 important

Comment: @AmalHashim nothing changed with min-height setting, even the F12 tool will not refer to the custom css file i defined for this section.... of course on other pages the custom css will have effect..

Comment: Is the custom css loaded on that page? Try clearing browser cache.

Comment: @AmalHashim i tried clearing the cache, but seems the custom css will not have any effect on the dialog ...  for example inside the custom css i define a custom color for the page header , link color all will work well... but not sure why i can not modify the dialog box height using the same approach ? maybe i need to use java-script ?

Comment: @AmalHashim do u have any suggestions ?

Comment: You can try removing inline style using JavaScript. It will be tricky to find event to associate..

Comment: not sure why  sharepoint is being very buggy in some cases and there is not a standard way to fix the issues !!

Comment: @AmalHashim  i wrote the following inside a javascript  "var element = document.getElementsByID('resultcontent');
element.removeAttribute('style');" but did not have any effect either

Answer (score 0):

It might be getting overridden somewhere else. You can try

```
#resultcontent    
{
    height:350px !important;    
}
```

Also, the x64 version of IE typically does not play well with SharePoint. Try the 32 bit version.

Comment: ya i know about IE 64x ,, but most of our users use IE 64 bit and it will be hard to force them to use IE 32

Comment: Then they should be aware that there is limited functionality using that browser.

Comment: i tried this "#resultcontent    
{
    height:350px !important;    
}
.ms-pickerresultdiv
{
    height:350px !important;    
}" but did not change anything ...

Comment: Is your custom CSS file even being loaded in the dialog? The dialogs have their own master page as I recall.

Comment: using the F12 tool i can not see any effect of the custom css on the dialog box,, i am referencing the custom css inside the Seattle.master layout page,, so will this affect the dialog box ?

Comment: @PiratecEric now i tested this using IE 32-bit and i face the same problem, so seems that the problem is not related to the IE 64 bit..